# Create a cron job to automatically clear cache

Tags: cron

I'm trying to clear cache automatically with a cron job but it didn't work.
I'm debugging simply on the browser at this link *website-url/cronjob.php*.
I think it's a problem with the syntax, I have tried to *truncate* the tables from database.

As you can see in the code attached below, I've tried two methods, but neither one works.

```
\Drupal::database()->truncate('cache_config')->execute();
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE yqxq_cache_config');
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE yqxq_cache_container');
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE yqxq_cache_data');
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE yqxq_cache_default');
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE yqxq_cache_discovery');
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE yqxq_cache_dynamic_page_cache');
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE yqxq_cache_entity');
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE yqxq_cache_menu');
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE yqxq_cache_render');
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE yqxq_cache_toolbar');
?>
```

What do I need to change to make this script work?

This is an example of query from the statistics view, which doesn't update if I don't run clear cache.

```
<?php
$count_users_tot = db_query('SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM {users}')->fetchField();
print $count_users_tot;
?>
```

Comment: Drupal has build in mechanisms to clear caches. One of them can be found on the status page. Another way is to use drush.

Comment: I know that, but I don't need these options. I'm the developer for my client's website and I need to run clear cache automatically every x minutes to refresh some database queries...

Comment: Don't flush everything, bad practice. What exactly are those db queries doing anyways? Drupal 8 should be automatically invalidating cache if a field value changes.

Comment: I edited the question and added one query from my view. It's calculating the users that are staying longer than 60 minutes without premium membership.

Comment: Like sssweat already mentioned, it is bad practice to clear caches. Once a day can have valid cases, but every few minutes, and then all that is in your query you are taking huge performance penalties. If you only need to refresh database queries you better have a look at drupal tag based caching mechanisms https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-tags

Comment: @NoSssweat is right: Completely emptying the cache tables is not necessary. Also, Drupal doesn't use any cache for the executed queries; the question should make clearer the relation between executed query and which data is cached.

Comment: Ok, so I need somehow to refresh the query.

Comment: It's not the query that needs to be refreshed. If the query were executed from a controller when rendering a page, then it would be the page to be cached. Since you are executing the query from an external script, there isn't any cache involved. Are you sure the cron task is not "visiting" a Drupal page which is executing the query and returning a value? The question doesn't make that clear, and they are two different cases.

Comment: The query is executed inside the view. The results are not refreshed until I will clear the cache, that's why I've tried to create a cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to *@No Sssweat*, *@kiamlaluno*, *@Rick B*, I've got an answer.
Firstly, I learned that is not a good practice to clear cache automatically every minute or so often.
Secondly, I figured out that I can solve this problem without using a cron job at all, but I have to understand these tag based caching mechanisms.

The problem was as in the image attached below, *Page-Caching was Tag Based*, so selecting *None* option solved my issue.

[image]